# OBD2 protocol in trucks

Tags: obd-ii, mercedes-benz, truck

How can I check if these trucks are OBD2 compatibile?

Trucks:

1. Mercedes Atego, type 818 [Daimler 970.21]
2. Man, type 8.113

If they are compatible with this protocol can you tell me where can I find that connectors in the truck?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your simplest approach to find out if any vehicles have OBD2 is to look at the manufacturer's website, speak to your service centre or read the manual. These will also tell you where the connectors are.

Comment: Hi, I don't own this trucks. I just need to make a program for it and I don't have any of the documentation that you have mentioned. I have tried to send an email to manufacturers but I haven't been lucky.